# how to properly replace axios api with fetch api and map over the received data in nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, fetch-api, node-fetch

this is the link of the entire file - [asyncActions.js](https://github.com/arkapratimsarkar/redux-demo/blob/main/asyncActions.js)

the part with axios api -

```
const fetchUsers = () => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(fetchUsersRrequest());
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((res) => {
        // res.data is the array of users
        const users = res.data.map((user) => user.id);
        dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(users));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // error.message gives the description of message
        dispatch(fetchUsersFaliure(error.message));
      });
  };
};
```

Function Output -

```
{ loading: true, users: [], error: '' }
{
  loading: false,
  users: [
    1, 2, 3, 4,  5,
    6, 7, 8, 9, 10
  ],
  error: ''
}
```

replacing the part with fetch api -

```
    const fetchUsers = () => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(fetchUsersRrequest());
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((res) => {
        const users = res.json().map((user) => user.id);
        console.log(users);
        dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(users));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(fetchUsersFaliure(error.message));
      });
  };
};
```

the OUTPUT -

```
{ loading: true, users: [], error: '' }
{
  loading: false,
  users: [],
  error: 'res.json(...).map is not a function'
}
```

what am I doing wrong ? why can't I map over the data ?

Comment: res.json() return an Promise

Comment: yes. how do handle that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `res.json()` will return a Promise. You need to add a second then block:

```
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((res) => {
   const users = res.map((user) => user.id);
   console.log(users);
   dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(users));
 })
.catch((error) => {
   dispatch(fetchUsersFaliure(error.message));
});
```

Comment: IT worked. thanks. I didn't know about the second block